Test if a date is in a given period
I have a table t1 with a "ColDate" field. I would like rows whose ColDate is between the start and end of the month. I have a date_py variable, I would like get the month before date_py then take the lines according to the month before
from datetime import datetime
date_ = datetime.today()
date_py = date_aujourdhui.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

sql_query = f"""
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE "ColDate" >= DATE_TRUNC('month', '{date_py }'::date - INTERVAL '1 month')
AND "ColDate" < DATE_TRUNC('month', '{date_py}'::date)
"""
table = pd.read_sql(sql_query, connexion)

Erreur
LINE 4: WHERE "DateMES" >= DATE_TRUNC('month', '2024-06-28'::date - ...
                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.


Did you try re-writing the expression so you could use <= instead of >=?  Or maybe not <?

Which dbms are you using? (It's product specific in several ways.)

You are getting the error because you are defining ColDate as a string in your WHERE clause.  Your query should be:
sql_query = f"""
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE ColDate >= DATE_TRUNC('month', '{date_py }'::date - INTERVAL '1 month')
AND ColDate < DATE_TRUNC('month', '{date_py}'::date)
"""

